# Generate map PDF using react-simple-maps and @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, react-simple-maps

in my use case, I have maps generated using the `react-simple-maps` component, I need to generate the pdf of this map, I'm trying to do this using the `@react-pdf/renderer` component, but it's not working!

[React-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/)

[React Simple Maps](https://www.react-simple-maps.io/)

See the example on CodeSandbox!

[image]



Can anyone who works generating maps with react-simple-maps and manages to generate the pdf using @react-pdf/renderer or any other component, can you point me to a solution to solve this problem?


I thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are dependent on the users browser unless you use one of your servers browsers. Here I am saving the Demo as PDF However there are a few oddities the Site is trying to send as 3 pages so I need to select 2 of 3 (1 and 3 are blanks)
As with ALL PDF outputs the browser needs to Download and then send to the viewer I don't always use the inbuilt Acrobat Browser Viewer (its exploitable) so this map opens safely outside the browser.

[image: j58g73ru93q5o459g7wi6m37y]

If you save the SVG on the server and run say a headless print it should behave correctly as a single page

[image]